# How to limit the number of wordpress search results from each category on each result pagel

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type, custom-wordpress-pages

I am using the code below to show search results for different post types separately/segmented form.

```php
if (have_posts()) {
    // In the below line of code you can set the loop order in array (1, 2, 3, 4)
    // You can also turn a post type off by removing it from the below line.
    $types = array('post', 'page', 'sfwd-courses', 'product');

    foreach ($types as $type) {
        // Here you can customize both the titles, section heading title & side title
        if ($type == 'post') {
            $head_title = "Results in Posts";
            $side_title = "post";
        }
        if ($type == 'page') {
            $head_title = "Results in Pages";
            $side_title = "page";
        }
        if ($type == 'sfwd-courses') {
            $head_title = "Results in Courses";
            $side_title = "course";
        }
        if ($type == 'product') {
            $head_title = "Results in Products";
            $side_title = "product";
        }

        // This div below shows up the head title for each section
        echo '<div class="search-section"><h4>' . $head_title . '</h4></div>';
        while (have_posts()) {
            the_post();
            if ($type == get_post_type()) {
?>
                <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(''); ?> role="article">

                    <header class="article-header">

                        <div class="article-header-content">
                            <h3 class="title head-2"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                            <!-- This div below shows up the side title for each section -->
                            <div class="posttypetext"><i> <?php echo $side_title; ?> </i></div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- <?php get_template_part('parts/content', 'byline'); ?> -->
                    </header> <!-- end article header -->

                </article> <!-- end article -->
        <?php }
        }
        rewind_posts();
    }
} else {
    get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'missing');
}
```

This shows me a list of search results showing all the posts first and then the results from pages, then courses and finally products.

The pagination limit right now is 20 per page.

I want that on each page I should get `5` search results from post, `5` from page, `5` courses and `5` products.

this is needed because if there are 30-40 posts results, it will cover up the first 2 pages of search results and users will not see any courses or products that will be lying on the 3, 4 page.

I hope it makes sense, is there a way to accomplish that?

Thanks
JS

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to set this up. The simplest way is to take advantage of the `current_post` property of your query which would give you the index number of the current post.

So in your code you could replace this line:

```php
if( $type == get_post_type()){
 // your template section
}
```

With this line:

```php
global $wp_query;
if( $type == get_post_type() && $wp_query->current_post <= 4){
 // your template section
}
```

It's `$wp_query->current_post <= 4` because `current_post` is zero based and you only need to output the first 5 posts!

There are others ways to achieve the same thing using `wp_query`, but you haven't provided any details about how you've created your query. You just provided us with your `loop` template, we don't know how it's been queried and where this loop is located. So I think using `current_post` property would be simplest way here!

Comment: Hi Ruvee, thanks for looking into it.
I am basically using 'if (have_posts()) {' on the search.php file inside the wordpress theme. So I guess the default search query is being used.

Do you think this can be achieved by structuring the query in a better way or by customizing it?

Comment: Not a problem! To me the solution I just gave you sounds fine! Please give it a shot and let me know if it works the same way you would want to!